# matching manytomany fields in django

Tags: django, many-to-many, view, tagging

What I want to do is simply match the images to the department model through tags. How do I write a view for my department page to do this? I have looked everywhere but can't find the answer. Please help!

Models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  tag_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.tag_title

class Image(models.Model):
  image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Department(models.Model):
  page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  content = models.TextField()
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.page_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Image.objects.filter(tags__department=d) #where d is your deparment.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

Given a `Department` object `department_obj`:

```
images = Image.objects.filter(tags__in=department_obj.tags.all())
```